# Flexible layout with hide/show of panel

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

We want to set up a UI like this, where `A` cards are shown by default, and if needed `B` shows on the right side:

Before:

```
┌────────────────────┐
│┌───┐┌───┐┌───┐┌───┐│
││A  ││A  ││A  ││A  ││
│└───┘└───┘└───┘└───┘│
└────────────────────┘
```

After:

```
┌────────────────┐┌──┐
│┌──┐┌──┐┌──┐┌──┐││  │
││A ││A ││A ││A │││B │
│└──┘└──┘└──┘└──┘││  │
└────────────────┘└──┘
```

So note in the beginning, the container for the `A` cards take up the full width, then when `B` shows, the `A` cards shrink a bit in width, and `B` takes up about 1/6 of the width.

This is how `v-container`, `v-layout`, `v-flex` etc. are set up right now:

```
<v-container fluid>
  <v-layout>
    <v-flex>
      <v-card>
        <v-container fluid grid-list-xl>
          <v-layout row wrap>
            <v-flex xs6 sm4 md3 lg2 xl1 v-for="record in records" :key="record.id">
              <v-card flat tile>
                  <!-- "A" code -->
              </v-card>
            </v-flex>
          </v-layout>
        </v-container>
      </v-card>
    </v-flex>
    <v-flex v-show="showPanel">
        <v-card>
          <!-- "B" code -->
        </v-card>
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>
</v-container>
```

The way the code runs now is that it shows "Before" okay, but for "After" it shows just a thin column for `B` like 1/12 of the width of the screen, and the `A`s squeeze in just a bit. Anything I do to change the width of `B` just screws up the layout completely, like takes 50% of the width, or has `A`s showing in three or fewer columns instead of four.

I think my structure might be fundamentally wrong, but I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around how `v-container`, `v-layout`, and `v-flex` are supposed to work, and the documentation is not helpful.

Comment: Can you try `<v-flex v-show="showPanel" xs2>` ?

Comment: @Toodoo – very thin panel, like 1/12 or less.

Comment: You can also try to reproduce minimal viable example: https://template.vuetifyjs.com/

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KbZydO?editors=1111 Does it answer your question ?

Comment: @Toodoo – it seems to push the B panel to the end, so if there are more rows, it will appear there at the bottom, but thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirmed it was the `fluid` in the line `<v-container fluid grid-list-xl>` that was causing troubles. Once I removed it, layout was as expected. The problem couldn't be duplicated in CodePen likely because the template was rendered in another environment with its own layout rules, so whatever conflict there was showed up only in that context.